# Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, powershell-3.0

I am using Window PowerShell to import XRM Solution in MS crm 2011.

And using the following cmdlets

PS> Import-Module “C:\Program Files (x86)\Xrm CI Framework\CRM 2011\PowerShell Cmdlets\Xrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.dll”

PS> Import-XrmSolution -ConnectionString $ConUrl -SolutionFilePath $path -OverwriteUnmanagedCustomizations $true

Then the PowerShell throws a Exception:

Import-XrmSolution : The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:59.8729770. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the 
SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
At C:\Users\rkhalid\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\Automated.ps1:35 char:5
+     Import-XrmSolution -ConnectionString $ConUrl -SolutionFilePath $path -Overwr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-XrmSolution], TimeoutException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TimeoutException,Xrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.ImportXrmSolutionCommand

Should I increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding?

I am not sure but I think increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding but I don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, and I increased the timeout value in the target server connection string.  The default is 2 (minutes).  Try setting it to 5 or so and then wrapping the `Import-XrmSolution` call in `Measure-Command{ Import-XrmSolution }` to see how long it takes (if you are curious).

```powershell
$targetCrmConnectionUrl = "ServiceUri=http://your-server/your-organization/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc; Domain=your-domain; Username=your-username; Password=your-password; Timeout=5"
```